# Pip within virtualenv is global pip

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, pip

I've got a virtualenv installation that seems a bit broken.

When I create a virtualenv using `virtualenv .`

It says everything is fine:

```
New python executable in ./bin/python2.7
Also creating executable in ./bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip...done.
```

I then `source bin/activate` to activate the virtualenv.

However, when I do `which pip`, I get the global pip. I take a peak into the `bin/` folder and notice that pip isn't actually installed, so I can't even point to it directly.

I then tried to install pip in the virtualenv using `easy_install`, but it turns out that even that easy_install is pointing to the global `easy_install`, and surprise, there is no easy_install in the virtualenv's `bin/` folder.

The contents of the bin folder are:

```
activate  activate.csh  activate.fish  activate_this.py  python  python2  python2.7
```

My virtualenv version is 1.11, python is 2.7.5, this is all running on webfaction, for which I think it's commonly known that virtualenv poses some problems? I have a working virtualenv though already installed on the server, so that's strange to me.

Comment: Did you try to create your virtualenv like this ? `virtualenv venv --no-site-package --distribute` I don't know but it may solve your problem in some way or another.

Comment: it's a newer version of virtualenv. both --no-site-packate and --distribute are deprecated and have no effect.

Comment: Damn you're right, I've never seen that before. (Although I'm always up to date with the last version)

Answer (score 0):

I've run into a similar problem running `virtualenv` and `pyvenv`, but usually when the `--no-pip` or `--no-setuptools` options are passed. You can install `pip` inside the environment by activating the virtual environment and using `easy_install` to install `pip` into the environment:

```
$> cd path/to/my/env
$> source bin/activate
$> easy_install pip
```

This is assuming that your environment got `easy_install`, which from your `ls` looks like a "no"... But you can get `easy_install` by installing `setuptools`. Have you tried regenerating the environment with `virtualenv` again?